Differential Privacy: when the tokenizer is related to the dataset
So I want to train a model with DP-SGD. However, I noticed that by how my input dataset is constructed, the tokenizer is actually related to the input data. (e.g., picking out a sample may affect how other samples are tokenized) So in this case, the model output would go through the tokenizer in the end to decode, and this will break the guarantee the DP-SGD brings right?
If it is true, I wonder if the tokenizer leakage can be composed to the DP-SGD guarantee for a looser bond?
